# PERFORMANCE: Creating a variable vs repeating 'get()' function

Tags: android, performance

Which of the following ways is preferable to handle the string data? (Java Android)

1)

```
EditText edit = (EditText) ...
String text = edit.getText().toString();

someFunction(text, text, text, text);
```

2)

```
EditText edit = (EditText) ...

someFunction(edit.getText().toString(), edit.getText().toString(), edit.getText().toString(), edit.getText().toString());
```

At first sight it would feel natural to store the string in a variable (1), but there is the "Garbage collector" thing which consumes resources.

This google documentation https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html gives some hints but I can't really understand them.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about GC.

Comment: In this case, readability will be the only concern. The other differences are negligible. Use the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really think the first method would be better. As  you're performing the toString()  method four times in the second but only once in the first.

Also a direct reference instead of using a getter method can perform better.Though it might be negligible.

[In Java is there a performance difference between referencing a field through getter versus through a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195849/in-java-is-there-a-performance-difference-between-referencing-a-field-through-ge)