# Integer equals method - a question regarding current implementation

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, looking at Integer.java implementation, I see the code for 'equals' method is this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Integer) {
            return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I don't understand why the line

```
return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
```

calls the method intValue(), why can't it directly use the value like this

```
return value == ((Integer)obj).value;
```

and save a method call. I thought this is aimed to cope with user class which extends Integer. However I see Integer class is declared **final**. So for performance perspective I think the direct use of value is more efficient.

At [In Java is there a performance difference between referencing a field through getter versus through a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195849/in-java-is-there-a-performance-difference-between-referencing-a-field-through-ge) there are several answers, some says that using methods vs direct access to variables has minor effect on performance, and other says it has up to 7 times penalty, unless inlined by the compiler. Anyway it has some kind of penalty.

This is not a duplicate of [In Java is there a performance difference between referencing a field through getter versus through a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195849/in-java-is-there-a-performance-difference-between-referencing-a-field-through-ge) as
I'm asking here about the specific code of Integer.java. It seems as a glitch, and the right code shall be

```
return value == ((Integer)obj).value;
```

What do you think?

BTW, The question is also about the other objects alike Integer e.g Long,Short etc.

Comment: This is indeed not a duplicate. The real answer to this question is related to Java intrinsics - methods implemented natively, see a list of intrinsics methods at https://gist.github.com/apangin/7a9b7062a4bd0cd41fcc. `Integer#intValue()` is one of these and will likely be faster than direct field access.

Comment: It is still a little strange to use the getter method instead of the value itself. anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I agree that answer including intrinsics analysis is more relevant here, and I am also voting for reopening the question. However the main reason for marking the question as duplicate was "If your application is slow, this isn't the reason why.". Are you going to compare a lot of `Integer` objects?

Comment: About 7x slowdown - I cannot find that exact quote in the link, so I am not sure if this is still relevant. While I *can* believe (actually I doubt, but I still *can* believe)  in 7x slowdown for Android devices, I do not think it is that important for backend or desktop apps.

Comment: about the 7x slowdown, it is really mentioned about android. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26214405/5778803 
I'm not trying to find reason why application is slow. I'm a java beginner, coming from the world of C, and while learning java, I'm examining some of the sources of the basic classes, in order to learn from it. That's why I asked about the redundant usage of a method call where direct access is possible.

Comment: @EliyahuM, the answer you have mentioned contains a link to android docs. Were you able to find a reference about 7x slowdown on the linked [android dev site](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#GettersSetters)? I did not find it, therefore I doubt if it is still relevant.

Comment: I did not follow the link to android dev site, just looked at the answer at the discussion forum (at stackoverflow). As it was posted 4 years ago, it is probably not relevant anymore.